# Vuejs - check if two data of different lists are same to display in the template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to compare to list of data ( one is fetched from the server, and the other is from the default data).

Data from server:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "day": "14 April 2017",
    "time_list": [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "time": "11:00 AM",
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "time": "08:00 PM",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "day": "13 April 2017",
    "time_list": [
      {
        "id": 33,
        "time": "11:00 AM",
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "time": "02:00 PM",
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Default data of the front end javascript Vue component:

```
default_time_data: ["11:00 AM", "02:00 Pm", "05:00 PM", "08:00 PM"]
```

What I would like to do is in the template:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="day in show_routine_data">

        check if the time from the day.time_list is same as the showTime_count

        For each default_time of default_time_data, check if any of the time of day.time_list is equal to the default_time.

        If the default_time is equal to the time, then show its id.
        Else, show no data
    </div>
</template>
```

I hope I was clear, if not please do ask. I have been scratching my head since this morning to solve this problem. Could you please help me out.

**update:**

I want the final data to display like this (from the above data):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>14th April 2017</p>
        <ul>
            <li><p> 25 </p></li>
            <li><p> No data </p></li>
            <li><p> No data </p></li>
            <li><p> 28 </p></li>
        <ul>
    <li>
    <li>
        <p>13th April 2017</p>
        <ul>
            <li><p> 33 </p></li>
            <li><p> 22 </p></li>
            <li><p> No data </p></li>
            <li><p> No data </p></li>
        <ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `check if the time from the day.time_list is same as the showTime_count` - what is `showTime_count`?

Comment: For this data, you want to output ids 25, 33, 22 ? (11am and 02pm)

Comment: @wostex Hi. I have updated the question, could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a `computed property` where you gather your data which is ready to be rendered. Docs about computed properties: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Computed property is the way to go if you need to extract a piece of data, format it somehow, etc.

Also you need two `v-for` loops: one to loop through blocks and a nested one to loop through time ids.

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myArr: [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "day": "14 April 2017",
        "time_list": [
          {
            "id": 25,
            "time": "11:00 AM",
          },
          {
            "id": 28,
            "time": "08:00 PM",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "day": "13 April 2017",
        "time_list": [
          {
            "id": 33,
            "time": "11:00 AM",
          },
          {
            "id": 22,
            "time": "02:00 PM",
          },
        ]
      },
    ], 
    default_time_data: ["11:00 AM", "02:00 PM", "05:00 PM", "08:00 PM"]
  },
  computed: {
    dataToRender: function() {
      return (this.myArr && this.myArr.length > 0) // if data is already fetched
        ? this.myArr.map(e => Object.assign({ day: e.day }, 
          { 
            timeList: this.default_time_data
              // if time in default array - return id, otherwise 'No data'
              .map(dt => (e.time_list.map(({time}) => time).includes(dt)) ? e.time_list.find(tl => tl.time === dt).id : 'No data')
          }))
        : []; // if data hasn't arrived - return empty array
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
   <ul v-if="dataToRender.length > 0"> <!-- check if data exists -->
     <li v-for="item of dataToRender">
       <p>{{ item.day }}</p>
       <ul>
         <li v-for="time of item.timeList">{{ time }}</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```